# How can I highlight all the desired paths in a digraph plot?

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph

I have a graph and I want to find all the nodes accessible from the node 'O1' so I use the following:

```
B=[1 1 1 0 ; 0 1 1 0; 0 1 0 1; 0 1 0 1; 0 0 0 0 ; 0 0 1 0; 1 1 1 0; 0 1 0 0];   
nNodeCol = size(B,2);                            % one node for each column of B
nNodeLine = size(B,1)/2;                         % one node for every two lines of B
% First the column nodes, then the line nodes:
nodeNames = [cellstr(strcat('O',num2str((1:size(B,2))'))) ; cellstr(strcat('S',num2str((1:size(B,1)/2)')))];
% Adjacency matrix adj, adj(i,j)=1 means there is an edge from node#i to node#j:
adj = zeros(nNodeCol+nNodeLine);                 % square matrix which size is the number of nodes
adj(1:nNodeCol, nNodeCol+1:end) = B(1:2:end,:)'; % edge from a column node to a line node is added for all the 1 in the first line of the node in the matrix
adj(nNodeCol+1:end, 1:nNodeCol) = B(2:2:end,:);  % edge from the line node to a column node is added for all the 1 in the second line of the node in the matrix
% Creation of the graph:
G = digraph(adj,nodeNames);
h = plot(G); 
v = dfsearch(G,'O1');
highlight(h,v,'nodeColor','r');
highlight(h,v,'edgecolor','r');
```

The cell array `v` contains the following:

```
'O1'
'S1'
'O2'
'S2'
'O4'
'S4'
'O3'
```

But my problem is when I plot the results, not all the edges are shown: 
[image]

As you can see, the node highlights are correct. However, some of the edges are not shown in red, like the connections `O1-S4` and `S1-O3`. How can I show all the edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the missing edges to show up by using the [`'edgetonew'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.dfsearch.html#inputarg_events) option for [`dfsearch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.dfsearch.html) and modifying the call to [`highlight`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.highlight.html) as follows:

```
v = dfsearch(G, 'O1', 'edgetonew');
h = plot(G);
highlight(h, v(:, 1), v(:, 2), 'nodeColor', 'r', 'edgeColor', 'r');
```

[image]

Note that the direct path from `O1` to `S4` is not highlighted, but the indirect path through `S1` and `O2` is. If you would rather highlight the direct path, you can use [`bfsearch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.bfsearch.html) for a breadth-first instead of a depth-first search:

```
v = bfsearch(G, 'O1', 'edgetonew');
h = plot(G);
highlight(h, v(:, 1), v(:, 2), 'nodeColor', 'r', 'edgeColor', 'r');
```

[image]